# How to convert List to String without commas and brackets

Tags: java, arraylist, printing

Suppose array list is already created with elements a, b and c in them.
but i only want to print the elements without the brackets and commas.
would this work?

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
String word = list.get(i);
String result = word + " ";
}
System.out.print(result);
```

Comment: Plug that code (and everything you're omitting) into an IDE, compile it, and run it.

Comment: compiler error for result.

Comment: You mean an array of String which already have commas and brackets within them? i.e. "foo,bar","baz" ?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it easily using replaceAll method like

```
 String result = myList.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").replaceAll(",", " ");
```

Try the below program. Hope it meets your needs.

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList.add("a");
        myList.add("b");
        myList.add("c");
        String result = myList.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").replaceAll(",", " ");
        System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: why separate replace for character ',' you should add ',' to the same regex

    ex : "[\\[\\],]"

Comment: No, the first replace is for removing [ and ] while the second replace is for replacing "," by " ". Note the difference between "" and " "

Comment: yep. missed that. sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No it won't work.

- Result needs to be outside the loop
- You need to append to result rather than overwriting it each time

Fixed.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("horse", "apples");

String result = "";   //<== needs to be outside the loop
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String word = list.get(i);   
    result = result + word + " ";  // <== need to append 
}
System.out.print(result);
```

Other things to bare in mind

- Enhanced for loop is easier to use in this case
- StringBuilder better for massive lists
- Java 8 String.join() can do this in one line without the trailing space
- You don't need intermediate variable for word

For example

```
for (String item : list) {
    result += item + " ";
}
```

Or just use String.join

```
String.join(" ", list);
```

Answer (score 0):

`result = word.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", " ")`